# Validate form using a loop and label elements as required

Tags: javascript, validation, loops

So basically I need to validate a form that has several different element types. I need check if textboxes have a value entered if and if dropdown boxes have a value selected etc. After I have determined they do or don't, I need to display a red asterisk next to the text fields that are missing values, or an asterisk next to the dropdown box that doesnt have a value selected. For example sake, I made a short representation of what I am talking about. I think the problem occurs when my loop reaches the radios? Any guidance is greatly, GREATLY appreciated!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

    .error {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
    }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

function validate()
{

var errorMess = document.getElementById('errFname');

for (i=1;i<5;i++) 
{
var form1 = document.forms['webForm'].elements[i];
var errPar = paragraphs[i-1];
if (!form1.value) 
{
errPar.innerHTML = "Required";
}
else 
{
errPar.innerHTML = "";
form1.value.trim()
}
}
return false;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="webForm" action="#" onSubmit="validate()">
<fieldset>
<legend>Legend2</legend>
    input1:<input id="txt1" name="txt1" type="text"/><p class="error"></p>
    input2:<input id="txt2" name="txtl2" id="txtlname" type="text"/><p class="error"></p>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Legend1</legend>
    <input name="radio1" type="radio">radio1
    <input name="radio2" type="radio">radio2<br>      
    input3:<input id="txt3" name="txt1" type="text"><p class="error"></p>
    input4:<input id="txt4" name="txt4" type="text"><p class="error"></p>
</fieldset>
<input name="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes to your code, mostly for demostration purpose. If you prefer to keep yous it's fine as well. take a look at my concept. It seems like you forgot to put your radio buttons in a group thou.

here's a fiddle of my demo (highly recommend you use it in the future for questions)
http://jsfiddle.net/pMUX3/2/

```
function validate() {
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var txtcounter = 0;
var rcounter = 0;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {        
    //for text field
    if (inputs[i].type != null && inputs[i].type == "text") {
        if (inputs[i].value == null || inputs[i].value.trim() == "") {
            paragraphs[(txtcounter<2?txtcounter:txtcounter+2)].innerHTML = "Required";
        } else {
            paragraphs[(txtcounter<2?txtcounter:txtcounter+2)].innerHTML = "";
        }
        txtcounter++;
    }

    //for radio button
    if (inputs[i].type != null && inputs[i].type == "radio") {
        if (!inputs[i].checked) {
            paragraphs[rcounter+2].innerHTML = "Required";
        } else {
            paragraphs[rcounter+2].innerHTML = "";
        }
        rcounter++;
    }
}
}
```